# Как посчитать количество записей по дням в PgSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица:

| id | date_created | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-19 10:14:24 | registered |
| 2 | 2021-03-20 10:14:24 | logged |
| 3 | 2021-03-21 10:14:24 | registered |

Каким запросом можно получить количество элементов, создаваемое каждый день с type = registered? Хочу получить что-то вроде:

| date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-19 | 1 |
| 2021-03-21 | 1 |

Comment: *с type = registered* `WHERE` *создаваемое каждый день* `DATE()` + `GROUP BY` *получить количество элементов* `COUNT()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось вот так:
SELECT DATE(date_created) AS date, COUNT(*) AS users_count FROM user_log where type = 'registered' GROUP BY DATE(date_created) ORDER BY date